# Connect the azure IoT hub with a GSM modem using Azure IoT C SDK

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, modem, azure-iot-sdk

I want to connect an embedded system to the Azure IoT hub. The system consists of a STM32 microcontroller, some sensors and a modem with the following features:

- IP packet transfer protocol
- TLS support
- SHA-256 support
- control via hayes command set (AT commands)

I want to extend my code base by the usage of the [Azure IoT Client C SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client).

1. Is it possible to use this library with the mentioned modem?
2. If yes, can somebody outline the necessary steps for integration?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is fairly broad and not very specific I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STM has integrated the C SDK into their Cube for simple connection with Azure.  Please take a look at this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-platform-support#partner-supported-platforms) to find the appropriate link for your STM microcontroller.

If the microcontroller you use is not supported, you can always port our SDK to any platform by following the [porting guidance](https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/devdoc/porting_guide.md).

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Is it possible to use this library with the mentioned modem?

From the details provided I see no reasons for not being possible.

#### 2) If yes, can somebody outline the necessary steps for integration?

[This github repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-device-ecosystem) has some examples on how to connect boards with STM32 microcontroller.

Also note [from here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c):

> The minimum requirements are for the device platform to support the
>   following:
>
> - Being capable of establishing an IP connection: only IP-capable devices can communicate directly with Azure IoT Hub.
> - Support TLS: required to establish a secure communication channel with Azure IoT Hub.
> - Support SHA-256 (optional): necessary to generate the secure token for authenticating the device with the service. Different
>     authentication methods are available and not all require SHA-256.
> - Have a Real Time Clock or implement code to connect to an NTP server: necessary for both establishing the TLS connection and
>     generating the secure token for authentication.
> - Having at least 64KB of RAM: the memory footprint of the SDK depends on the SDK and protocol used as well as the platform targeted. The
>     smallest footprint is achieved targeting microcontrollers.
>
> ...
>
> If you are considering porting the device client SDK for C to a new
>   platform, check out the [porting guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/devdoc/porting_guide.md) document.